# DLookUp conflicts with data validation; how to unlink text box in form from table?

Tags: ms-access

I have a `DLookUp` function such as:

```
=DLookUp("[Products]![price]","Products","[productID]=" & [Products.productID])
```

This is present inside a form. When `productID` is entered, the price is automatically filled using the above function. However, when attempting to save the record, I am returned with my validation error, `Price cannot be zero` (validation rule is `<>0`). Why is it saying this when the price isn't zero?

Is it possible to unlink this text box from the table completely, so it doesn't try to store information at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should read like:

```
=DLookUp("[price]","Products","[productID]=" & productID & "")
```

But it doesn't make much sense; it just retrieves a price.

What is your form to, and how do you set the field Price of the form?

Comment: My expression seems to work as expected both with mine and yours. That is correct - all I want to do is retrieve a price and display it for user reference. The field Price in the form is fetched automatically from `Products` table. This is a form to enter feedback. I don't want the price field to be added to the `Products` table, I just want it there for reference. I don't know if I'm making much sense now...this has been giving me grief all day.

Comment: If possible, I just want to make it so specific text boxes do not try to save data to their table.

Comment: If the expression is for look-up only, the cause for your troubles must be found elsewhere.

Comment: I just fixed the issue accidentally, I changed one of the fields to reference from ProductID as a foreign key, rather than primary. Works as expected now.